# How to make a SVG that has a fixed height and a relative width?

Tags: svg

I want to create an SVG that has always the same fixed height(in my case 40px) but with a relative width. How can I do that? It always changes the height when I resize the browser.

I tried setting the preserveAspectRatio to multiple variations, but I probably don't understand It quite well.

Here's a snippet showing what I'm trying to accomplish

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>
      Header one
    </th>
      <th>
      h2
    </th>
      <th>
      Header three 333
    </th>
      <th>
      h4444
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 400 40" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect x="0" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" width="80%" height="40px" fill="#000" /> 
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 400 40" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect x="0" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" width="80%" height="40px" fill="#000" /> 
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 400 40" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect x="0" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" width="80%" height="40px" fill="#000" /> 
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 400 40" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect x="0" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" width="80%" height="40px" fill="#000" /> 
      </svg>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the height to be fixed(40px or so) in every column, but It adjusts based on the weight of the column. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not very sure if this is what you need. Please try this instead of what you have: `<svg viewBox="0 0 400 40" version="1.1" width="100%" >`  If this is not what you need please add an image with the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the width of the viewbox to % unit:
`<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100% 40" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <rect x="0" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" width="80%" height="100px" fill="#000" /> 
</svg>`